# Pick off 'first' dates using cal function in bash

Tags: text-processing, awk, date, cal

I'm trying to pick off the first Monday, second Tuesday, second Saturday, etc. out of the `cal` function and piping `awk` commands. For this month, I can get the **first Tuesday** correctly with the command below the calendar:

```
    December 2018
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31

>cal | awk 'NF == 7 && NR > 2 {print $3; exit}'
>4
```

But this doesn't always work, see the test for March 2016 below:

```
     March 2016
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30 31

>cal 3 2016 | awk 'NF == 7 && NR > 2 {print $3; exit}'
>8
```

Why does it work for the top example but not the bottom? I would think the bottom example should look at the third line and find the correct result of `1`. Is there a fool-proof way to snag these dates using `awk` -- maybe checking if the column is empty and moving to the next line?

Comment: The third row doesn't have 7 fields

Comment: Do you have to use `cal`? Do you have GNU `date`?

Comment: I see about the `NF==7` part, but removing that gets hairy if Sunday and Monday are missing and the first day of the month is Tuesday. I do have `date`.

Comment: yes you can use `substr`: `cal | awk 'NR>1 && (d=substr($0,2*3,3)+0){print d; exit}'`

Comment: What about other key dates like the first Thursday, second Monday, third Friday, etc.? The answer works but could you explain the syntax?

Comment: @Foxer adjust the `day` and `nth` vars: `cal | awk 'NR>1 && (d=substr($0,(day-1)*3,3)+0) && --nth < 1{print d; exit}' day=2 nth=1`. The +0 will convert from string to number, and will be 0, thence false if the string is just spaces or letters, the `NR > 1` is to avoid the year number from the first line.

Comment: @mosvy just seen your suggestion. That ought to be an answer. And assignment inside a comparison should be red-flagged ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution for you

```
cal | awk 'NR >= 3 { tu = substr($0,7,2) +0 } tu { print tu; exit }'
4

cal 3 2016 | awk 'NR >= 3 { tu = substr($0,7,2) +0 } tu { print tu; exit }'
1
```

It picks out the Tuesday column (characters 7 and 8), and delivers the first non-zero value. The approach can be safely extrapolated to any day of the week.

Comment: This is a simple, clean function -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU date:

For the first Tuesday of the current month:

```
for day in 0{1..7}; do [[ "$(date -d $(date +%Y%m${day}) +%a)" = "Tue" ]] && echo "$day";done
```

For the first Tuesday of a given year and month:

```
year=2016
month=03
for day in 0{1..7}; do [[ "$(date -d ${year}${month}${day} +%a)" = "Tue" ]] && echo "$day";done
```

A "Tuesday" variation in awk:

```
cal | awk -F "" '!/[[:alpha:]]/ && $7$8 ~ /[0-9]/ { print $7$8;exit }'
```

This checks the hard-coded position of columns 7 and 8 (Tuesday's) in the output (notice the field separator is null, splitting the input on every character) -- after skipping any lines that have letters in them (the header lines). Adjust the 7 & 8 to get other days.

To make it clearer what the previous command is doing, the awk command's fields are numbered per column:

```
123456789            <--- awk fields $1, $2, $3, ... $9
    December 2018
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31
```

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. These examples are great. I'm not sure I understand the 7 & 8 part regarding the columns -- how do these values get the third column in cal? I plugged in other values and don't see the pattern.

Comment: Take a look at the recent edit and see if that helps.

Comment: Ah that makes sense -- thanks for the clarification. We have a lot of files released on first, second, third [day of the week] of the month etc. and some are released but not updated until the following Saturday. Since `crontab` cannot handle this type of schedule these little functions are perfect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Both `gcal` (GNU) and `ncal` (BSD) families support options for transposing rows with columns:

```
$ ncal
    March 2024        
Su     3 10 17 24 31
Mo     4 11 18 25   
Tu     5 12 19 26   
We     6 13 20 27   
Th     7 14 21 28   
Fr  1  8 15 22 29   
Sa  2  9 16 23 30   

$ gcal -i

March 2024

Sunday          3 10 17 24 31
Monday          4 11 18 25   
Tuesday         5 12 19 26   
Wednesday       6 13 20 27   
Thursday        7 14 21 28   
Friday       1  8 15 22 29   
Saturday     2  9 16 23 30
```

When invoked this way, it’s easier to pluck ordinal positions by day of week. Use `awk` to first pattern match the desired day of week, then print column N-1 to get the Nth instance of that day of week.

For example, 1st Tuesday of specific months and years:

```
$ ncal 12 2018 | awk '/^Tu/ { print $2; }'
4
$ ncal 3 2016 | awk '/^Tu/ { print $2; }'
1
```

To get the 5th Friday of the current month (which happens to have one):

```
$ ncal | awk '/^Fr/ { print $6; }’
29
```

Answer (score 0):

In ksh93:

```
$ printf '%(%F)T\n' 'first monday this month'
2024-03-04
$ printf '%(%F)T\n' 'second tuesday this month'
2024-03-12
$ printf '%(%F)T\n' '2nd tuesday in 2016-03'
2016-03-08
```

(note that [4th, 5th don't work in current versions of ksh93u+m](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/733); `fourth`, `fifth` do though).